# {quotation} and {quote}

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Could someone please enlighten me what the difference between [quote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quote) and [quotation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotation) is. Should they be merged?

Also, recently there were some questions about quotation marks, that used one (or both) of these tags. Should we add [quotation-mark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotation-mark), or is [punctuation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation) enough (or maybe add a synonym?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`quotation` and `quote` are names of LaTeX enironments. They are different, though closely related. Nevertheless, I don't think it's worth to distinguish. Though I would not pick one and convert to other one into a synonym.

I suggest we use the concept tag [quoting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quoting) similar to our other concept tags [compiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compiling), [installing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installing) etc. and convert [quote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quote) and [quotation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotation) into synonyms of [quoting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quoting), which now covers further quoting environments and packages. Also by this, we would merge, so questions with both tags would keep only [quoting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quoting).

Answer (score 6):

I think they are just two different notations of the same thing.

The [Wikipaedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation) of *quotation* says the same:

> A **quotation** or **quote** is the repetition of one expression as part of another one, ...

Some people just used the first and others the second form and once both tags existed they popped up automatically when someone write `quo...` in the *Tags* field. Most people don't know the difference as well so they tag their questions with both, just to be sure.

I would say they **should be merged**, e.g. [quote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quote) as synonym of [quotation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotation).

And [punctuation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation) should be enough. Questions about [quotation-mark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotation-mark)s can simply be  tagging with both [quotation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotation) and [punctuation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation).

Comment: I agree, except with the last sentence. I think that questions about {quotation-mark}s should just be tagged {punctuation}.

Comment: fyi, you can use [tag:tagname] syntax to make the tags clickable.. this is preferable to typing {tag} in post bodies.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff, I realized this recently. Is there a way to make them point to *meta* instead? I mean for tags which are only used on *meta*.

Comment: yes do [meta-tag:tagname]

Answer (score 6):

It seems like there is consensus. Could some mod please merge [quote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quote) and [quotation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotation) to [quoting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quoting).

Comment: How about {quoting} as the "consolidated" tag?

Comment: @lockstep: Thanks, that is what I actually wanted to write.

Comment: done

Comment: @Joseph: thank you